# Why does Django ORM return unicode for integer fields

Tags: django-orm

I have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    some_int_field = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True, default = 1)
```

And a view:

```
#...
result = something * int(my_model_instance.some_int_field)
#...
```

`my_model_instance.some_int_field` returns unicode, that's why I have to turn it to int explicitly which is not the most pleasant experience. It seems strange for me that I have to turn an integer field into integer. I googled, but failed to find any solution. Is there any way to ged rid of this necessity ?

Comment: Did you try making sure that the database field is numeric and that any stale bytecode files have been removed?

Comment: Stupid me. Yes, you're right. It was IntegerField in Django, but char in database